# How can I use "paste" as a condition in a conditional panel environment?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use the following *paste* as a condition in a conditional panel.

```
paste0("input.selection", input.Counter).
```

The condition is dynamic and depends mainly on the input *Counter*, which is an action button. Hence, I am trying to produce for example a string like

```
input.selection1
```

for input.Counter = 1. Since the conditions are already in quotes, I always get an error back. I would very much appreciate any help here. More precisely, I used the following code:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(,
   sidebarPanel(
            conditionalPanel(paste0("input.selection", input.Counter), uiOutput("test")),
            actionButton("Counter", "next")),
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
   output$test <- renderUI({
      radioButtons(paste0("choice", input$Counter), label = h4(""), choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3), selected = FALSE)
   })
})
```

Comment: add `collapse=""` in your paste call ?

Comment: @ Tensibai. Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately there is another error now, object 'input.selection' not found. However, the input selection is definitely there.

Comment: Then try to make a [mcve] and give the full error. We can't help on guessing. I'm not working with Shiny so I just guess your `input.Counter` return an empty value (or you did mistype the error, can't tell)

Comment: @ Tensibai. Sorry for that, I added a reproducible example. Thank you for your time - I very much appreciate it!

Comment: I'm may be blatantly wrong but, shouldn't it be `input$Counter` instead of `input.Counter` ?

Comment: I think this should be correct. See for example here: [link](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html)

Comment: I can't see any input anywhere in your code, sorry but this out of my scope.